# Convert integer to numeric/double for dplyr::if_else()

Tags: r, class, if-statement, dplyr

I have a complex if_else() statement (see 3rd code chunk), which has several new if_else statements rooted in the 'false' condition.  if_else() requires types in the true and false conditions to be the same.

For some reason, I cannot coerce a simple dataframe, `chromSizes`, from integer to numeric/double so that types agree.  No errors are thrown during conversion - it simply remains as integer class.  I've tried multiple iterations, including `lapply`, `as.numeric()`, `as.double()`.  Nothing has worked.

In an isolated if_else() statement, using "0L" as the false condition works, whereas "0" throws the same error that I get in my complex if_else() statement.  So converting `chromSizes` to numeric/double should similarly resolve the Error in my complex if_else() statement.  See the 2nd code chunk.  Further, if I remove this line from my if_else() statement, the code chunk runs fine.

I might be able to use the base::ifelse() function, but would rather continue with if_else() throughout my statement.

```
chromSizes <- read.csv("sacCer3_chrom_sizes.csv", row.names=("Name"))
> chromSizes
         Length
chrIV   1531933
chrXV   1091291
chrVII  1090940
chrXII  1078177
chrXVI   948066
chrXIII  924431
chrII    813184
chrXIV   784333
chrX     745751
chrXI    666816
chrV     576874
chrVIII  562643
chrIX    439888
chrIII   316620
chrVI    270161
chrI     230218
chrM      85779

> str(chromSizes)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Length: int  1531933 1091291 1090940 1078177 948066 924431 813184 784333 745751 666816 ...

> as.numeric(chromSizes$Length)
 [1] 1531933 1091291 1090940 1078177  948066  924431  813184  784333  745751  666816  576874  562643  439888  316620  270161  230218   85779

> str(chromSizes)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Length: int  1531933 1091291 1090940 1078177 948066 924431 813184 784333 745751 666816 ...
```

```
> leading4 <- if_else(df.b$Chromosome_Strand == "-" & is.na(lead(df.b$Chromosome_Strand)), chromSizes[df.b$Chromosome,], 0)
Error: `false` must be an integer vector, not a double vector.

> leading5 <- if_else(df.b$Chromosome_Strand == "-" & is.na(lead(df.b$Chromosome_Strand)), chromSizes[df.b$Chromosome,], 0L)
> leading5 
[1]      0      0      0      0 576874
```

```
> SGD_YeastGenes7 <- SGD_YeastGenes %>%
+   dplyr::filter(Qualifier != "Dubious") %>% #Remove rows with Qualifier = Dubious
+   dplyr::mutate(ORFstart = if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "+", Chromosome_Start, Chromosome_Stop)) %>% #Define ORF bp start site
+   dplyr::arrange(Chromosome_Start) %>% #Sort by chromosome start position
+   dplyr::arrange(Chromosome) %>% #Sort by Chromosome number
+   dplyr::group_by(Chromosome) %>% #perform following operation only if chromosome numbers match
+   dplyr::mutate(UpstreamORF = if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "+" & is.na(lag(Chromosome_Strand)), 1,
+                                       if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "-" & is.na(lead(Chromosome_Strand)), chromSizes[Chromosome,],
+                                               if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "+" & lag(Chromosome_Strand == "+"), ORFstart - lag(Chromosome_Stop),
+                                                       if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "+" & lag(Chromosome_Strand == "-"), ORFstart - lag(ORFstart),
+                                                               if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "-" & lead(Chromosome_Strand == "+"), lead(ORFstart) - ORFstart,
+                                                                       if_else(Chromosome_Strand == "-" & lead(Chromosome_Strand == "-"), lead(Chromosome_Start) - ORFstart, 0)))))))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `UpstreamORF`.
x `false` must be an integer vector, not a double vector.
ℹ Input `UpstreamORF` is `if_else(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Chromosome = "chrI".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: That's strange.  What happens if you divide `chromeSizes$Length` by 1.0?

Comment: Note that this code sample isn't really reproduceable because you are referencing data frames that are not provided in the example.  In the future, make sure someone can paste your code into an editor and run it.  Simplify if necessary.

Comment: 1) Please create a small but reproducible example. 2) Show expected output for it. 3) It would be helpful if you remove all the `>` from your code, it makes it really difficult to copy code and we have to manually remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you didn't convert the data frame to numeric, at least not in any of the code you provided.  I'll do it for you:

```
# Read in sample data
chromSizes <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
Length
chrIV   1531933
chrXV   1091291
chrVII  1090940
chrXII  1078177
chrXVI   948066
chrXIII  924431
chrII    813184
chrXIV   784333
chrX     745751
chrXI    666816
chrV     576874
chrVIII  562643
chrIX    439888
chrIII   316620
chrVI    270161
chrI     230218
chrM      85779')

# Convert to numeric
chromSizes$Length <- as.numeric(chromSizes$Length)

# Check and see that it is numeric
is.numeric(chromSizes$Length)
# [1] TRUE
```

Then the `if_else()` should work:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
df.b <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
Chromosome_Strand Chromosome
x          chrIV   
y          chrXV   
z          chrVII
-          chrXII  
a          chrXVI
b          chrXIII 
c          chrII
-          chrXIV')

# Run if_else condition with numeric 0 FALSE condition
leading4 <- if_else(df.b$Chromosome_Strand == "-", chromSizes[df.b$Chromosome,], 0)

# View results
leading4
# [1]       0       0       0 1078177       0       0       0  784333
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple.  I didn't realize as.numeric(x) needed to be saved.  I assumed it simply applied to the existing df.  *facepalm*